# Android ADB has moved and Eclipse is looking in the old place

Tags: android

I did an SDK update last night and it moved adb.exe.  In its place it left a file called "adb_has_moved.txt" saying

> The adb tool has moved to platform-tools/
>
> If you don't see this directory in your SDK, launch the SDK and AVD
>   Manager (execute the android tool) and install "Android SDK Platform-tools"
>
> Please also update your PATH environment variable to include the
>   platform-tools/ directory, so you can execute adb from any location.

So I did all that, including the PATH and now I can start adb.exe from any DOS prompt.   But I **still** can't start it from Eclipse (Galileo 3.52).   When I try it says

> Location of the Android SDK has not been set up in the preferences

... which is not true.   The SDK IS set up in Preferences.  The real problem is at the top of the Preferences window where it says "*Could not find C:\SDK\android-sdk-windows\ **tools** \adb.exe!*"    ...No kidding  -  the update moved it to C:\SDK\android-sdk-windows\ **platform-tools**.    Because it's specifying a specific (wrong) path Eclipse is bypassing the PATH variable.  So how do I get Eclipse to look in the right place?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and updating Eclipse did the trick.  **Eclipse -> Help -> Check for Updates**.  Also see http://sagistech.blogspot.com/2010/12/can-not-find-adbexe-after-android-sdk.html.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the ADT plugin from within Eclipse might help, as detailed here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Alternatively, I guess you could always make the directory 'tools' in C:\SDK\android-sdk-windows and copy adb.exe in there - a bit of a hack but it should work :)

Comment: This who problem started because I installed SDK tools r9 last night.  Updating the ADT helped a LITTLE.   Now I can see my list of Virtual Devices.   Some of them start, some of them crash.  But I can't attach to them.  When I do Run as... Android application  nothing happens.    And if I do Run>Run Configurations I get a com/android/ddmlib/InstallException.  So there's some incompatibility between the SDK tools r9, the SDK, the ADT and Eclipse 3.52.      How do I get a working development system again?

Comment: OK I got it working.   Here's the deal:  the r9 tools apparently require the matching SDK so you can't install them over the old SDK.  So I tried installing the new SDK, with the new ADT already there.  During installation it recognized the ADT already being present so the autoloader didn't try to install a new copy, but afterwards it couldn't find it!   So finally I wiped the disk clean of all SDK/ADT/etc stuff and installed the SDK from scratch along with the ADT, ddms and other stuff.  That did the trick, but what a pain in the ***!!!

Comment: @PeterNelson I went through the same crap you did. But after a week o this madness, I witched back to Linux. Nothing like it :)